# Write unbuffered on python 3

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to create a file on python without buffer, so its written at the same time I use write(). But for some reason I got an error.
This is the line I'm using:
`my_file = open("test.txt", "a", buffering=0)
my_file.write("Testing unbuffered writing\n")`
And this is the error I got:
`my_file = open("test.txt", "a", buffering=0)
ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`

There is anyway to do an unbuffered write on a file?
I'm using python 3 on pyCharm.
Thanks

Comment: you can only write unbuffered in binary mode - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error isn't from Pycharm.

From Python documentation:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off **(only allowed in binary mode)**

Your code only works in **Python 2** but won't work in **Python 3**. Because **Strings** are immutable sequences of Unicode code points in **Python 3**. You need to have bytes here. To do it in **Python 3** you can convert your unicode `str` to `bytes` in unbuffered mode.

For example:

```
my_file.write("Testing unbuffered writing\n".encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 11):

use

```
my_file = open("test.txt", "a")
my_file.write("Testing unbuffered writing\n")
my_file.flush()
```

Always call flush immediately after the write and it will be "as if" it is unbuffered

Comment: Preferably use `with open("test.txt", "a") as my_file:` which closes and flushes upon leaving that context.

Comment: @jrc i guess for some use cases you might not want to close the file